# How to access SQL DB in C++?

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, cross-platform

I am looking for a free cross-platform (Windows, Linux) C++ library for an access to an MS SQL server DB.

For example, I want to convert the following C# flow to unmanaged C or C++ (from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)) :

```
static void Main()
{
    string connectionString = 
       ConsoleApplication746.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = 
           new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Igor: How about using SQLite?

Comment: Isn't SQLite an implementation of a DB, and not a library to access an existing DB?

Comment: @Igor Oks: you are creating confusion here because you don't tell us *which* SQL db you are talking of. Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, Sybase, IBM DB2, ... ??? Or are you looking for a generic library for different DB vendors?

Comment: Why do some people think MS has invented the word "sql server"?

Comment: @Ben: really? "SQL Server (TM)", not "MS SQL Server(TM)"?

Comment: @Doc Brown: Yes, really. SQL Server®. http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/Trademarks/EN-US.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing MS SQL server from windows should not be a problem in general. For accessing it from Linux, this web page may help you to find a way

```
http://www.sommarskog.se/mssqlperl/unix.html
```

Finding a solution that works on both Windows and Linux is a task that may not be solved easily, depends on the exact requirements and your current architecture. For example, when you just need C++ program calling a Perl script which does the DB work for you, this path may provide you with a free cross-platform solution. Perl is free and cross-platform, and the DBI modules too.

On the other hand, when your cross-platform C++ program uses a cross-platform framework like Qt, and you need a direct connection in your C++ program to the SQL server, ODBC may be the best option:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/sql-driver.html

Unfortunately, according to the information behind my first link, there are no free ODBC drivers for Linux, so you might bite the bullet and buy one.

Answer (score 4):

Try [DTL](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/) or [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/).

Edit: or [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to rewrite perfectly good, tested, working code.

Don't do it. Use Mono to run your existing code on Unix/Linux instead.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, SQLite is an implementation of a DB where data is stored in a flat file.

I think ODBC might be the technology you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What about SQLAPI++? Works both on Windows and Linux/Unix. http://www.sqlapi.com/.

Comment: It is not free, as far as I know